# Project has been whitelisted for access for Google Analytics Account Setup and Configuration APIs but I still can't use it

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I requested for premission and received an email that says:

> "Great news! We’ve received your request to join the Google Analytics
>   Account Setup and Configuration APIs Beta and your project has been
>   whitelisted for access. These APIs allow you to programmatically
>   create and edit properties, views, and goals."

When i  try to create a webproperty, by using `analytics.management.webproperties.insert`

```
Webproperty wp = service.Management.Webproperties.Insert(body, id).Execute();
```

i got this error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Your project does not have access to this feature. [403]

    Errors [
        Message[Your project does not have access to this feature.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
    ]
```

i tried even to use Googles API Explorer and the message is the same:

```
"code": 403,
"message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."
```

Comment: its enabled, I double checked, i can retrieve the webproperty list correctly for example

Comment: The API Explorer is an independent project from yours, and is not whitelisted.  you [can use your own API key/OAuth 2.0 client ID with the Explorer](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#CustomCreds) which should work if you use the project ID you whitelisted. Short answer is,  ensure that you are using the correct project, most people have lots of projects IDs, and you might not have whitelisted the correct one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried today my code again and it worked!! the ProjectID was correct. I got the whitelisted email to soon ^^

Comment: I have a similar issue, but the problem is I can't find the link for asking the whitelisting. How can I start that process?

Comment: @DavidRodriguez i filled up this form: [link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf01NWo9R-SOHLKDUH0U4gWHNDBIY-gEI-zqBMG1Hyh3_hHZw/viewform?fbzx=7168207752763639000)

Comment: Thanks @YoshiakiNakamura